# A good reference for functional programming in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, design-patterns

I've searched the web (*and evaluated books on online shops*) but I'm not satisfied with articles found on the subject.

If you search the web with keywords **C#** and **functional** you find a lot of *basics* or *Linq* articles.

I'm also disagree with the first reply to this question:

[Are the functional programming features provided in C# rich enough? What's missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522222/are-the-functional-programming-features-provided-in-c-sharp-rich-enough-whats)

After all F# is built on .NET (as C#) and is a functional language widely used and with good reputation.

Is there out a set of good articles, a book or even techniques explained here about good functional patterns that can be **profitably used in C#**?

As said I'm searching nor introductory material nor guides on specific technologies (like Linq, which I use and love).

I'd like also to hear if a particular technique can be safely exposed to a reusable library Public API (*hope this not too off-topic*).

Comment: Requests for books/articles/etc. are not in scope for SO.  SO is not a recommendation engine and the format of the site simply doesn't support requests for lists of things.  Product recommendations are esentially shopping questions, which aren't appropriate on SE sites as discussed in: [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: It may be better (and more on-topic) to ask for specific features. Note that linked answer is so 2009 and there is much better type matching and async code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real-World Functional Programming: With Examples in F# and C# [Paperback]
Tomas Petricek (Author), Jon Skeet (Author)

[Amazon Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988924)

From the Amazon book description:

> Real-World Functional Programming is a unique tutorial that explores
>   the functional programming model through the F# and C# languages. The
>   clearly presented ideas and examples teach readers how functional
>   programming differs from other approaches. It explains how ideas look
>   in F#-a functional language-as well as how they can be successfully
>   used to solve programming problems in C#. Readers build on what they
>   know about .NET and learn where a functional approach makes the most
>   sense and how to apply it effectively in those cases.

Comment: I'm sorry, suspecting a possible close of the question... @Srikant Krishna, thank for suggestion, it perfectly ask my question.